# Почему не переходит по ссылке?

Tags: php, html

Я в Open Server. В папке domains два моих сайта:  `maket`  и  `families`

```
domains// 
  maket//
    index.php
  families//
    index.php
    page2.html
```

```
<A HREF="..\families\index.php"> Родные</A>  // ссылка 1 
<A HREF="..\families\page2.html">             page2  </A> //ссылка 2
```

Захожу на сайт   maket, выбираю любую из  ссылок 1 или 2. ИМЕЮ КОД ОШИБКИ 404.
При наведении курсора на ссылку, CHROME показывает, что запрошен файл из maket/families/, а не из domains/families/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем ссылки внутри локального хостинга в вашем случае ни верные пути
Надо делать ни через `../` а через одиночный слеш т.е `/`

Вот дэмо:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот то что я делал:

```html
// Папка maket index.php

<h1>maket/index.php</h1>

<a href="/families.inc/index.php">families/index.php</a>
<a href="/families.inc/page2.php">families/page2.php</a>
```

```html
// Папка families/index.php

<h1>Families/index.php</h1>


<a href="/maket.inc/index.php">maket/index.php</a>
<a href="page2.php">families/page2.php</a>
```

```html
// Папка familes/page2.php

<h1>Families/page2.php</h1>

<a href="/maket.inc/index.php">maket/index.php</a>
<a href="index.php">families/index.php</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй )

```
<A HREF="../families/index.php"> Родные</A>
<A HREF="../families/page2.html">page2</A>
```

Answer (score 0):

Дроп "/" не правильно поставлен.

Comment: Чем Ваш ответ отличается от уже ранее опубликованных?